# Perfect hash function to obfuscate a sequential value

Tags: c#, algorithm, perfect-hash

Here is what I need (language: C# 4):

I am building a system where you can submit complaints. After complaint has been submitted you are given a unique 9 digits number that identifies your complaint in the system.

For security (security through obscurity) purposes I do not want ticket IDs to be sequential. But I **do** want to use database to generate sequential id.

So what I need is a injective function that is fast both ways: sequential number to my ticket id, and back from ticket id to the sequential number.

So that my `ticketId` in database is sequential, but before showing it to a user I will obfuscate it, similarly, when I get a number back from the user, I de-obfuscate it and use it to look up complaint in the database.

The obfuscation part does not need to be too complicated, just "not apparent enough" for general public.

For example I could simply change bitness of the value, which will get me (for 8-bit values):

> 0 -> 0
>   1 -> 128
>   2 -> 192
>   3 -> 64
>   4 -> 160
>   5 -> 96
>
> etc.

Comment: Why do you need both a sequential and a 'random' number?  Why not just use the random number as the real ID?

Comment: Hashes are not supposed to be reversible.  If you can reverse it, it's called encryption.

Comment: 9 digits are really not that hard to brute-force

Comment: @Tim S. Not to answer for the OP, but sequential guarantees uniqueness while "random" does not (without checking for an existing ID each time)

Comment: This seems very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534225/generate-code-from-id-using-a-1-1-function/11547722#11547722

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem perfectly: Encrypt the ticket number with a constant key. [There is a 32-bit block-size block cipher that you can use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513056/which-good-block-encryption-algorithm-has-the-shortest-output)

Comment: Injective function does not map to a value more than once. It is a non-injective function that can results in ambiguous tickts.

Comment: Completely true. I removed that paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something along the lines of symmetric encryption. For example, if you apply the substitution and diffusion steps of the [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) encryption algorithm, you can get a number that can be quickly mapped back and forth but difficult to find a pattern. It is almost the same as your example but the S-Box and P-Box values are proved to be effective against cryptanalysis.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like this:

SHA1 your number, then store it in a table in your database along with your sequential number.  Then when you receive the hash, just look up the sequential number in the database.

FYI, this is not really security.  You should implement a real password system.

Comment: yes, "security through obscurity" is not a real security. That's why I said "security through obscurity".